# Capturing a variable from a lambda capture gives an error?

Tags: c++, lambda

The following code in VS2010:

```
void AddBishopMoves( vector<Move> &moves, uint64_t mask, uint64_t occupied, uint64_t valid )
{
  ForEachBit( mask, [&moves,occupied,valid]( Square from )
  {
    auto toMask = BishopAttacks( from, occupied ) & valid;
    ForEachBit( toMask, [&moves, from]( Square to )
    {
      moves.push_back( Move( from, to ) );
    });
  });
}
```

gives the error

> error C3480: '`anonymous-namespace'::::moves': a lambda
>   capture variable must be from an enclosing function scope

But i did capture "moves" by reference in the outer lambda.

Changing the code to assign moves to a temporary and capturing the temporary solves the error.  This gives no error in VS2010:

```
void AddBishopMoves( vector<Move> &moves, uint64_t mask, uint64_t occupied, uint64_t valid )
{
  ForEachBit( mask, [&moves,occupied,valid]( Square from )
  {
    auto& x = moves;
    auto toMask = BishopAttacks( from, occupied ) & valid;
    ForEachBit( toMask, [&x, from]( Square to )
    {
      x.push_back( Move( from, to ) );
    });
  });
}
```

The question is why?

Am I avoiding some subtle bug in logic the compiler is trying to warn me about?
Is this just not supported by c++11 capture semantics?
Or is this just a bugged feature?

Comment: Looks like a compiler-bug. Also, it is MSVS10 which is not to be trusted, anyway. It is broken the day it was released.

Comment: @Nawaz: That's a bit harsh, I think. MSVS10 is not perfect, but it's pretty good for most purposes.  And I haven't used a compiler without bugs.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Maybe. But in comparison to all other major compilers used today, MSVS10 has more bugs. So if a compiler has more bugs, then it is not to be trusted that easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [a known bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/725134) that seems to have been fixed, albeit too late for the VS11 Beta, as the bug is still present there.

Another simple work-around would be to just implicitly capture the variable in the inner lambda:

```
void AddBishopMoves( vector<Move> &moves, uint64_t mask, uint64_t occupied, uint64_t valid )
{
  ForEachBit( mask, [&moves,occupied,valid]( Square from )
  {
    auto toMask = BishopAttacks( from, occupied ) & valid;
    ForEachBit( toMask, [&, from]( Square to ) // <== implicit capture of 'moves'
    {
      moves.push_back( Move( from, to ) );
    });
  });
}
```

IMHO, you should generally just capture your stuff implicitly by reference, as I don't see any reason to do otherwise here.

Btw, thanks to you I discovered [another bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/730244), which may be related. Please upvote if you can.